# What kind of components and techniques were used to create Bitdefender's GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm curious as to what each of the components are on BitDefender's GUI. I've provided a picture in hopes that some could explain how this type of GUI was accomplished.

I'm not wanting to re-create the GUI, I'm just wanting to know if someone can name the components and perhaps tell me what they did to get that look and feel?

Thank you to anyone who spends the time explaining.

[image]

Comment: This question is very open ended. "What they did to get that look and feel" is a big design question.

Comment: @djechlin I'm not looking for a very specific answer. I would be completely content with something like: The 'Auto Pilot' is a JToggleButton probably with x-method overridden. Or The items in the scroll are customized JPanels with a gradient background. etc. I'm just wanting to know what the components are, from there I guess I can see what I can do to customize the components if I want to do something similar. I'm wanting to experiment more with customizing components.

Comment: [`CompassButtons`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513) is worth a look.

Comment: @trashgod Thank you for the reply I'll look into it. **Edit** Wow that is definitely neat! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing's GUI framework is very flexible, most likely the arbitrary components such as the big round button at the top were simply custom components with a nice looking skin.

The rest just look to be standard components with custom skins, for example the big rectangles housing the antivirus/firewall/antispam/update are just jpanels or even unselectable buttons. There are many ways to make something look how you want, and there's never one standard way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the big round button at the top is a custom component rather than using Graphics2D? Also, you mention that the rectangles house antivirus could be buttons? I wasn't aware one could add multiple components to buttons like that. Interesting indeed! Could you tell me your guess on the Auto Pilot button? As well as the scroll feature of the panels if you have the time?